# Retrieving multiple data from database

Tags: php, mysqli

Retrieving multiple data from database, working in xampp local server but didn't work in cpanel server. Database has been connected successfully. Some part is working well, Problem is only retrieving multiple data.

```
$sql_query_slider="SELECT * FROM slider ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $slide_limit ";
$result_slider=mysqli_query($dbconfig,$sql_query_slider);
<?php foreach ($result_slider as $res) {?>
    <?php echo $res['slider_desc']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: what result you will get when run in cpanel server ?

Comment: you need to fetch row from $result_slider ...check my ans

Comment: you forgot to fetch the query result as an array to use it in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**try this**

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_slider)) { 
var_dump($row);
 } ?>
```

You can not run a `mysqli_query` result through a foreach loop, as it is not an array. What you have to do is process the result through some form of `mysqli_fetch` function, in this case `mysqli_fetch_assoc` or `mysqli_fetch_array` which returns each row of the query result as an associative array.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_slider)){
     echo $row[1]; //this will print out the first index in the result array.
}
```

Comment: Actually it will print the second index. Indizes start with `0`.